# Change hours minutes and seconds

Tags: java

The time is set as hh:mm:ss, so time is 23:50:45, once it hits midnight it will turn to 00:00:00. A practise question for my exam has asked me to write a method to do this, is my logic right or away off, I  am concerned about my if else statements

```
public void increment()
{
if(seconds <= 59)
{
   seconds ++;
}
else if (seconds >= 60 && minutes<= 59)
{
   seconds == 0;
   minutes ++;
}
if(minutes >= 60 && hours <= 23)
{
   hours++;
   minutes == 0;
}
else
{
  hours == 0;
}
}
```

Comment: For starters, your clock should never read "60", that should be "00" so your `if` statements are "off by one"

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)? You are also mixing `seconds` and `secounds`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same thing much easier.

```
public void increment() {    
    seconds ++;
    if (seconds >= 60)
    {
       seconds = 0;
       minutes ++;
    }
    if(minutes >= 60)
    {
       hours++;
       minutes = 0;
    }
    if(hours >= 24)
    {
       hours = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are performing assignment operations using the `'=='` equivalence operator. Correct that...
Instead of `minutes==0;`, it should read `minutes = 0;` and so on as you are assigning '0'. The `==` will evaluate to a `boolean`. You have also used secounds some place, instead of `seconds`.

See [this](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter02/operators.html)!

Comment: `s/return/evaluate to`. Only functions return.

Comment: Sorry i will fix the seconds now, spelling errors are wild in me. And no i cant try it out on netbeans or anything as i'm at work and dont have access.

Comment: Take a look at Matthieu's answer. Your logic seems a little off. Hope it works for you...

Comment: Pain in the ass written java exams, netbeans or whatever IDE would have picked them errors up and I could have tested my logic properly but in an exam condition I dont have access to these so it will be 3 hrs of constantly checking my spelling.

Comment: Oh...exams huh? Good luck then!

Comment: Also would I need to use any sort of sleep method so that it takes exactly 1 second to change the seconds, dont think i would be able to work that out exactly in exam conditions mind

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is wrong...

```
if(secounds <= 59)
{
   seconds ++;
}
```

will cause seconds to go to 60... or remove the `else` in the `else if` coming right after...

As pointed out by anirudh4444, to assign to 0, you should use `=`, not `==`

I would just remove all the `<=` conditions. And replace the last one as

```
if (hours >= 24) {
    hours =0;
}
```

Also, spell seconds correctly (it was misspelled in some places are correctly spelled in one place...)

Your code becomes :

```
public void increment()
{
seconds ++;

if (seconds >= 60)
{
   seconds = 0;
   minutes ++;
}
if(minutes >= 60)
{
   hours++;
   minutes = 0;
}
if (hours >= 24)
{
  hours = 0;
}
}
```